# Taxonomy name repeating when showing 2 posts from each category

Tags: categories, loop, taxonomy

I am trying to get my page to show a custom taxonomy and then a the first 2 posts in that taxonomy,

My taxonomy is called types
post type is called guides

I want the page so it shows like this

**Type 1**
post a
post b

**Type 2**
Post c
Post d

**Type 3**
Post e
Post f

However, What I am getting is

**Type 1**
post a

**Type 1**
post b

**Type 2**
Post c

**Type 2**
Post d

**Type 3**
Post e

**Type 3**
Post f

my code is

```
$args = array(
    'type' => 'guides',
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'taxonomy' => 'types');

$categories = get_categories( $args );
        

foreach( $categories as $category ) {
echo '<div class="supcat">';
 echo '<h2 style="color:red;">' . $category->name . '</h2>'; // Display category name 


    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 2,
        'post_type' => 'guides',
         'tax_query' => array(
        array (
            'taxonomy' => 'types',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $category->slug
        )
    )
        
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    
    // The Loop
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
            
         the_title(); 
    endwhile;
    
    echo '</div>';
}

// Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Interesting question, this code is working fine on my test website.

Comment: Thanks for you response, I have also just tested my code on another website and it works fine on that site too. So this is a little weird. I will have a look at the website itself and see if there is anything else causing a conflict or something.

Comment: You can share full code of your page if you want)

Comment: I never got to the bottom to why it wouldnt work on the site I was building, I went another route in the end. But the code above does work on all other sites I tried it with